# enable cookies in Phantomjs + selenium

Tags: python, cookies, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to login in amazons3 (with the url：'https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential') on my armv7 board.I used phantom2.0.1 from [here](https://github.com/spfaffly/phantomjs-linux-armv6l) and selenium2.45.0.

I can open the website successfully, but when I doing 'submit' after filling the username and password, the website jump to an error page which shows ‘Please Enable Cookies to Continue’. So I wonder how to enable cookies for phantomjs in selenium.In my ubuntu12.04 with suitable version of phantomjs, I can succeed

Part of my code is below:

```
def __init__(self,username,password,login_url,width=1151,height=629):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.login_url = login_url
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)  
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ( "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Phantomjs/2.0.1 Safari/534.34" )  
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/bin/phantomjs',desired_capabilities=dcap,service_args=['--ssl-protocol=any','--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
    self.driver.set_window_size(width,height)

def _login_system(self):
    try:
        self.driver.get(self.login_url)
        print self.driver.page_source#I can success here
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(lambda driver : self.driver.find_element_by_id("ap_email")).send_keys(self.username)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(lambda driver : self.driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password")).send_keys(self.password)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(lambda driver : self.driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit-input")).submit()#failed here and showing Please Enable Cookies to Continue
```

Comment: PhantomJS supports cookies and they are enabled by default. Not sure, why this is an issue. Maybe that binary is bad.

Comment: @ArtjomB.Thanks for your answer.I've tried to compile phantomjs both on my armv7 board and qemu with the rootfs,but it failed all the time,I searched for this problem and someone mentioned it may be out of memory.Do you have any suggestions for compiling? Thanks a lot.make[2]: *** [generated/JSDOMWindow.cpp] Error 255 
make[2]: Leaving directory `/phantomjs/src/qt/qtwebkit/Source/WebCore' 
make[1]: *** [sub-DerivedSources-pri-make_first-ordered] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/phantomjs/src/qt/qtwebkit/Source/WebCore' 
make: *** [sub-Source-WebCore-WebCore-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer,
It seems that amazon does not accept "Phantomjs/(*.*.*)" in the useragent

fail:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Phantomjs/2.0.1 Safari/534.34

OK:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0 WebKit

In addition,I add "WebKit" at the end of the useragent,because of the problem "undefined is not an object"(https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/325)

What's more,I've met a problem of "raise BadStatusLine(line)"(like here:[enter link description here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6690)).And it may be caused by the dismatch
of the versions of selenium and phantomjs,so I use phantomjs1.9.8 instead(piksel/phantomjs-raspberrypi in github)

For the compile problem,if you are to compile on an arm board,you'd better use swap to extend the RAM.

Comment: Thank you for solving this! Worked for me on with Amazon as well.